# Passing routes from AppComponent to a navbar component?

Tags: javascript, angular

So following along the Angular2 route documentation I end up with a component similiar in design to this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './views/app.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavBarComponent]
})
@Routes([
    { path: '/home', component: TestComponent }
])
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    }
}
```

the template for the AppComponent includes `<navbar></navbar>` which maps to the NavBarComponent directive. It looks like this:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './views/navbar.component.html',
    selector: 'nav-bar'
})
export class NavBarComponent {

}
```

I would prefer all of my links for the router be stylized through the NavBarComponent class. Is there a way to get the data in the @Routes annotation on the AppComponent, to be accessible in the NavBarComponent class?

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution so that i can provide routes to the `FakeAppRootCmp` set up by the `ROUTER_FAKE_PROVIDERS` for testing purposes